# Strange charset encoding when browsing to a site

Tags: character-encoding, apache2, centos

I have recently moved my site over to a new host (VPS). Periodically when I browse to the site I see a string of data, such as --

```
    ��[�Rۺ� O���)��q.J�!l(�[�m2��8 �aɹ�ݙ�� ϓ�%�N���v�Mv'�-i]>----It�M�|�����p�B7���}����i��:�k\����~�Q.�մ��*BJ�soG���~�_ȸ���a���<�@HS}���\��R]ݕ ����\�\��A�caǬ(�QP��NE�� ����>����6����0��ZԹG��+oc���p�1]״�(�训錽oc�Z��%�Hwr��[����EX���G*o9p�� vڵ �HHW�C@{eT���@� =*U�%�Cz��J��jIAO"��q}�Q`U"�I�f��k�J�r����G��qcs[k�P��%�Bml�s��욃mh9"�1w�T��~�am���!+�p�K+i =J�t-%�O ީpU6l�P;�U��@T� 6l<�� �e���q�. N�E����Z�E���ў�1��.�j� ����4�/��pU&D�o�xW+��G��ہ����;�w���_ur�k�E�,#��Ġ���Д��.�A��t��/ ����\���{Ͼ=9�w�{jf��i������̹�C~�[���gc�;^��6��5�z)K��S��s����ku��l�7j�뇆�ɯr�6��WŜ�:7w��y}�e�1��;���������<�e|yV+l]7O�5u[?����V�`ҟ=�:\�^�}��_iY�����}9=���WEZ.l�ʞ�l���c�e+_82//h�!��V��o7g[��W�L��UU�����NtqG� b��b�]�i:�7�B��c���8wyUk}��k�����qʭ�I�xx�;��3]�Tw� ~-�w���m�o��K�4�ꃛsvsܻy,5���Qw�;|0�?�lY탃�˞�أ��p�g��枞36k����c��Z�{[�˂xO������K~|>�φ�֧Vùj�U�-/��� ѦL� �2}���� �R��-�b���ph� %?�֧��Q�]���B��kw�N���z#���e��F�S��~}�z﫦UE�j�i�T�a��~'^3^�:k_�&ds{���6�r�����l.W�R����IZ�� z��ȈD�Z;pt)��:�S(31�2\=�!M��>�XD�֔��;gD_��IoDfCG�F�D�a�G!Μl 9ա��SX��N�T� �,��$<�j�kl~�Tp܅����X��>�p ���v�FڮO�L�����k��V��.����:�wo��P=��o���?��W��Q<8������uݏ��HkQ��?��1��SiaF.0�(;�7M�P�n4��4�x�IR�<3�����6rF�Ɇx���΀~ӄ=}pߑ�u�)�K�&���ړH�<+��&̎ y���& � D��I��Kܦ(?���(|� w6-c���N��ڞF�b۶|��!�%�l�|"���j6���-^A���X�w�pڦ�X��(��������f�h�ؐqb'όtI#<�-�="" r@d��w���w,okd�+nd�c�����="" 1k�w="" [�="" u�a��="" �v="" 4i;4�c���0���yo�]��z="">,��!��C��Q��>���zF;�:=�=���~�x�} c��Z!�tp��x�ǽ�oc���3�m��!Q~��ĵF�$̌N�ʂ��C�[���BIQ��}���q�j��I�:PR5H���RGC#/FSgU�V�Xz��$4�����~�w�5�n=ջ��}s|�]n�t/B��NC"�k��FE����GK� �#�>'��<���1b^Y�"p|Ԫ)HޞT���*:���W! �����]���f`6+["<�t'��d�h+��ܤ~q����Ȥ(="">N-��X�++R��`ŷcj2hӌ�OyGg JhZB�A*XY/+iث+�s%�1u��>2e���h(z�c@�N��A�e��}�{V�4��lR�}�jc�@��nGm�3���#�0"?�-�F5�#�"&?�&�Ԙ��d�W�����2���j�f�f�H� �b4zSs�w�B�$�3��:K��R�Ի*'�Ri3!�(F�skd+��]�R�u��'�J�|�eѯ��N�I1�:�����&j���;��Ҽ�eQ=Җ�zf�� �� �-�P�D�@n�h?�x�Q@��(&6�|���G�w�#�+;���*ͩL���:��Wr�I�f�aR�A�T#Oy��.R�#��!�.0�c�Z�Nbc�zU!z��eղ�e�W�X3�"�ӎ��Rh�ȇ~��܈��;:�s�t�Qڏ��Q�P��KE�������B��Ɖ�s�л�� V,�Z.$�W���׊K#�OBҨM���|�:��rC�'��.7i��F�s�T/R��"�^�����J�֞(�v��fC�8G��l/t���ƣ�ľ�����>�`�s�4�K�G5�a�{��D����<ԯ���K�O��sD�$�c�_d�7���{� �� �W�w>.-=�F�Z�W�;F��$�e-4�m�y����<�IĽv���C�c���M�v��O6l���ml�[َ�D��c�<د����p0�3�8���O�/�:�Ih���!<������c��ny=��9��jeee��|ֱ|'�8D|y zz�і��3�u��u����b�y�*jG������< ��Z4���v��c��I{�h�FB�����â���'sŴ,a����G5�%l��( #1�k3s���j�r͔L-���._ƶG� X<��C��y�߷DΒ��I�}@Y��#dJ����NxcJ���~���V���&��7"
```

Here is the header as seen in Firebug --

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Sun, 04 Mar 2012 17:43:55 GMT
Etag    "1330883035"
Expires Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Sun, 04 Mar 2012 17:43:55 +0000
Server  Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
**Transfer-Encoding chunked**
Vary    Cookie
**X-Drupal-Cache    MISS**
X-Generator Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.3

Request Headers 
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  __utma=162614910.1950275874.1326920494.1328073656.1328201988.4; __utmz=162614910.1326920494.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); __utma=142212834.1354567149.1327029129.1329407721.1330721009.6; __utmz=142212834.1327029129.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); SESS9cac77df1227f59f7a6f85a5ce79093a=g49om8oemr508pag9qni57oj53; __qca=P0-556640154-1328084416252; DRUPAL_UID=1
Host    domain.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
```

I'm at a loss here. I have searched for a solution with no luck. I hope I have provided enough information to diagnose this problem. Thanks.

UPDATE: when the header when display is normal (differences in **)--

```
Response Headers
**Cache-Control public, max-age=0**
Connection  close
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  3354
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Sun, 04 Mar 2012 19:24:29 GMT
Etag    "1330883035-1"
Expires Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Sun, 04 Mar 2012 17:43:55 +0000
Server  Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
**Vary  Cookie,Accept-Encoding**
**X-Drupal-Cache    HIT**
X-Generator Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.3

Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  __utma=162614910.1950275874.1326920494.1330883191.1330887981.6; __utmz=162614910.1330887981.6.2.utmcsr=xz.allanbendy.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; __utma=142212834.1354567149.1327029129.1329407721.1330721009.6; __utmz=142212834.1327029129.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); SESS9cac77df1227f59f7a6f85a5ce79093a=g49om8oemr508pag9qni57oj53; __qca=P0-556640154-1328084416252; DRUPAL_UID=1; has_js=1; __utmc=162614910; __utmb=162614910.6.10.1330887981
Host    domain.com
**If-None-Match "1330883035-1"**
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` header here clearly says that the data is UTF-8 encoded. If it is not, then mess like the one in the example is to be expected, if there are any non-Ascii characters in the document.

Find out the actual encoding. If possible, convert the file to UTF-8 encoding. If that is not possible for some reason, check out whether you can affect the HTTP headers using a `.htaccess` file. Failing even that, you need to change all non-Ascii characters to character references or entity references.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is compressed with gzip but the header "Content-Encoding: gzip" is missing in the first case.